# Stop for loop repeating tables

Tags: codeigniter, for-loop, activerecord, html-table

I have a for loop inserting data into my table, works well.

Problem is each loop I wish for it to start a new row, but it starts a new table. any ideas how to fix this?

```
 <?php if (isset($records)) : foreach ($records as $row) : ?>

    <div id="mobile-content">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account Name</th>
                            <th>Balance</th>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row->bank_name; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row->bank_balance; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row->bank_start_date; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the code to loop inside the table body, not in the whole table code:

```
<div id="mobile-content">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account Name</th>
                <th>Balance</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        <?php if (isset($records)) : foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->bank_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->bank_balance; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->bank_start_date; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Note:** I've also remove extra `<tr>` because you need one row for the three cells.

I hope that helps :D

Comment: Thanks, looks right. ill try in my code. when it works ill accept your answer. thanks you